# Is it possible to remove a "folder" at the end of a URL using an .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, yii

so I have a bunch of URLs

```
http://foo.com/people/smith/john/1
http://foo.com/people/cartman/eric/2
http://foo.com/people/simpson/bart/3
```

I want to change the URLs like so

```
http://foo.com/people/smith/john/
http://foo.com/people/cartman/eric/
http://foo.com/people/simpson/bart/
```

So basically, I think I need to write a condition that looks for the folder 'people' and removes the third directory from the URL. Is this possible with my .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

In the htaccess file in your document root, try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^people/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/.+ /people/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

This redirects the browser (changing the URL in the address bar) from

- http://foo.com/people/smith/john/1

to

- http://foo.com/people/smith/john/

If you don't want the URL in the browser's address bar to change, remove the `,R=301` from the square brackets.